# Bundlename of an installed p2 installable Unit

Tags: java, osgi, equinox, p2

I'd like to get the name a Bundle will have after it has been installed out of a p2 installable Unit before installing it.

For example, I have a Installable Unit Feature group with the following feature.xml.

```
<feature
  id="com.xyz.example.feature"
  label="Feature"
  version="1.0.0.qualifier">

<plugin
      id="com.xyz.example2"
      download-size="0"
      install-size="0"
      version="0.0.0"
      unpack="false"/>

<plugin
      id="com.xyz.example3"
      download-size="0"
      install-size="0"
      version="0.0.0"
      unpack="false"/>

</feature>
```

After installing the Feature the Bundle will have the name of id when I list all bundles.
How can I get this id programmatically out of my installable Unit before installing it.

Answer (score 1):

`IIinstallableUnit` interface extends `IVersionedId`, which gives you the `#getId` method. For IUs of type `osgi.bundle` the ID is the BSN (bundle symbolic name).

Check http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fequinox%2Fp2%2Fmetadata%2FIVersionedId.html

Comment: Calling the #getId for my IU Group returns the Feature ID (com.xyz.example.feature.feature.group) and not the Plugin ID(Bundle ID)

Comment: of course, if you ask the feature group. you should ask the bundle iu